# Blue corners that won't go away when using border radius

Tags: css

Okay so I have three social media links at the bottom of my web page and they have these blue corners that will not go away. [image]

Here is my code for this:

```
.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li a {
  color: #fff;
  border: 0.5px solid #fff;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
  -moz-border-radius: 18px;
  -o-border-radius: 18px;
  -ms-border-radius: 18px;
} 

.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  text-align: center;
}

.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li, #bottomfacebook 
a:hover {
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li, #bottominstagram 
 a:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 0, 149);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li, #bottomtwitter 
a:hover {
  background: var(--blue);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
```

This my html:

```
<ul class="social footer">
    <li id="bottomfacebook"><a href=""> 
    <span class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>

    <li id="bottominstagram"><a href=""><span class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> 
    </li>

    <li id="bottomtwitter"><a href=""><span class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I do not know if it is because I am using fa fa icons, I checked the color code of that blue corners in my css but could not find anything that is the same as that color so it has be something to do with a specific property I gave my social media tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, what browser do you use? I can't replicate it with Firefox 74 here.

```css
.hd-footer-22-main {
  --blue: midnightblue;
}

.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li a {
  color: #fff;
  border: 0.5px solid #fff;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
  -moz-border-radius: 18px;
  -o-border-radius: 18px;
  -ms-border-radius: 18px;
}

.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  text-align: center;
}

.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li,
#bottomfacebook a:hover {
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li,
#bottominstagram a:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 0, 149);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li,
#bottomtwitter a:hover {
  background: var(--blue);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="hd-footer-22-main">
  <ul class="social footer">
    <li id="bottomfacebook">
      <a href="">
        <span class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    </li>

    <li id="bottominstagram"><a href=""><span class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    </li>

    <li id="bottomtwitter"><a href=""><span class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Edit: Updated CSS as per my comment.

Comment: Google Chrome, but it is supposed to run on all browsers. The blue corners go away completely if I take out all the border-radius properties.

Comment: It doesn't show up with the above snippet. BUT, if you define `--blue` as e.g. „midnightblue” and add additional rules for `li` (`list-style: none; display: inline-block;`) I can replicate the behaviour.

Comment: If confirmed, I'll update my answer so you can accept it :-)

Comment: Thank you for helping me, to fix it I had to take out this part of code **.hd-footer-22-main ul.social.footer li** as the last **li** properties took priority over all the other **li**'s in this **div**